# Why C# allows that only the last parameter in a method is of "variable length"

Tags: c#, .net, methods, parameters

From what I know, C# allows that only the last parameter of a method is of "variable length", for example:

`T f(A a, params B[] b)` allows that if you have `A r; .... B x, y, z; ....` you can call f like `f (r, x, y, z)`. Why C# doesn't also define something like:

```
T f(params A[] a, params B[] b)
```

Comment: How to determine where `a` ends and `b` begins then?

Comment: It's the same way in C++, and I believe C.

Comment: I would have thought this was pretty obvious as zerkms says...

Comment: @zerkms: When finish the elements of `A` type and start the elements of type `B`

Comment: @Tom: It is not that obvious as you think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351878/why-c-allows-that-only-the-last-parameter-of-a-method-is-of-variable-length/6351901#6351901

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because how would the compiler know when the variable arguments for the first parameter stop?

Pleas tell me what `argOne` and `argTwo` should contain inside of the method body:

```
void Foo( params object[] argOne, params object[] argTwo )
{
    // whatever
} 

Foo( 1, false, "Hello", new object(), 2.3 );
```

Comment: If I were OP I'd answer that compiler wouldn't have compiled such unobvious cases, but have compiled some more deterministic like `params int[] a, params string[] b` ;-)

Comment: @zerk: Yes.  However, the rules would be horrifyingly complicated.  See my answer.

Comment: @zerkms: And you would also have to avoid cases where there is an implicit conversion from one type to the other.  Too complicated and not very useful to justify the feature.

Answer (score 9):

Because it would be too complicated to determine when such a construction is actually allowed.
(When the call would be unambiguous)
Although it would be possible to create a good set of rules, they would be rather complicated and difficult to understand.  People would end up asking why case *X* doesn't work, if it has a subtle ambiguity.

For example:

- Neither type can be an interface or generic parameter
- If one type is an enum or a numeric type, the other must be a class other than `object` or `Enum`
- If one type is a delegate, the other must not also be a delegate type (nor `object`, `Delegate`, nor `MulticastDelegate`)
- One type cannot inherit the other
- All of these rules apply to any types implicitly convertible to the parameter types
- Both types must be `sealed` or must be value types

(some of these rules could be enforced at the callsite instead)

In practice, such a feature would have so many restrictions as to be almost worthless.

Therefore, this feature would [start with -10,000 points](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112024631/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points).

It would also create a whole new category of breaking changes.  Unsealing a type, adding implicit conversions, or other seemingly trivial things could now break client code.

Comment: "Too complicated" is an understatement; it is impossible in many circumstances (i.e., when implicit conversions are allowed).

Comment: Even C++, the king of dodgy syntactic constructions, doesn't allow this.

Comment: @EdS: No; it wouldn't be impossible.  It would just have a lot of `No`s.

Comment: Hence the careful use of "*many* circumstances" in my comment :)

Comment: @EdS: I thought you meant it would be impossible to write the rule.

Comment: Oh no, just terribly complex with a lot of restrictions, as you point out well in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because of ambiguity. If you went and did:

```
T f(params int[] a, params int[] b)
```

And you called:

```
f(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How would the compiler know where one started and the other began? You could argue that such cases could still be flagged as compilation errors and still allow the unambiguous cases to continue, but with inheritance it could get complicated and it just isn't worth it. Pass two arrays instead. I can't think of any situation that would merit two parameter arrays, and even then, it's syntactic sugar. There's no difference between it and just using arrays instead.

(Another example:

```
T f(params string[] a, params object[] b);
```

`string` inherits from `object`. This is still ambiguous...)

Comment: The only reason inheritance makes this complicated is because of a fundamental failing of the CLR type system, which it's designers admit was a mistake, to make `Array<T1>` convertible to `Array<T2>` if T1 inherits from T2. In a consistent type system then this would not be a problem at all. Not to mention that all overload resolution and such occurs at compile-time.

Comment: @DeadMG: Personally, I think the system makes sense - it allows `Array` to behave like any other class, instead of allowing special behaviour. Even so, that doesn't really change the way the compiler would recognize two `params` parameter arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It would pose question and lead to conflicts.

For example, let's say `B` inherits from `A`.

How would compiler understand:

```
f(A1, A2, B1, B2)
```

Would it mean `f({A1, A2}, {B1, B2})` or `f({A1, A2, B1}, {B2})`?

I think theoretically compiler could be smart and detect conflicts.
However, originally when .NET and C# itself were designed the idea was to try to avoid unambiguous and tricky cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many edge cases that make this an improbable feature.  Consider this example:

```
public static class Coolifier
{
  public static void BeCool<A,B>(params A[] a, params B[] b)
  {
  }
}

Coolifier.BeCool<string,string> ("I", "don't", "work.", "DO", "I", "?");
```

The example shows how there is no way to know where the first params [] ends and the next begins.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'last parameter' is of variable length, your second/third/n parameter woundn't be necessary 'cause would be contained into the first one according to your sample and would be ambigous:

```
T f(params A[] a, params B[] b)
```

b would be contained within a

Answer (score 0):

```
void DoSomething( params object[] p1, params int[] p2 )
{
...   
} 

 DoSomething( 1, 2, 3 );
```

Think if the compiler could resolve that. Can you code the '...' part? If yes, would it be readable?

I can tell you: It would be a *mess*.